# Cortex-M4 lock-up

Tags: c, gcc, arm, stm32, cortex-m

I'm trying to debug my application that is based on an STM32F3 uC running FreeRTOS. I have manually set the PSP to an invalid value (e.g. 0) at random places in thread context in the application expecting my memManageFault/busFault/usageFault/hardFault handlers to fire. Unfortunately none of the fault handlers are executed, but the core locks up on the first push to the invalid stack. What am I missing?

Some more details from the lockup state:

SCB->SHCSR: 0x74001 (all three faultHandlers are enabled, busFault pending, memFault active)
SCB->HFSR:0x40000000 (fault escalated to hardFault even though all handlers are defined and enabled)
SCB->CFSR: 0x28601 (BFAR valid, precise error)
SCB->BFAR/SCB->MMFAR: 0xfffffff7 (erroneous SP after sub, I assume)

PRIMASK/FAULTMASK/BASEPRI: 0
MSP: 0x2000ffe0 (still valid, the handler should run just fine)

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Is there any relevant code you could add to your question?

Comment: @JeffUK none really, I think there is nothing in the application that is specific to the issue

Comment: no reason to assume the bulk of the chip matches from one mcu to another even if both are STM32.  You have gone peripheral by peripheral and resolved the differences?

Comment: what specific from and to chips are you using?

Comment: @old_timer I'm sorry, did you mean to post these comments in response to my question? The uC itself is an STM32F303RE by the way

Comment: certainly, thought the F3 was not a cortex-m4 I see it is now.

Comment: try a breakpoint bkpt and you should get a prefetch abort.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like once again the core is right and I am wrong. The mistake I made was that although I have implemented the HardFault_Handler as a naked function, all the other fault handlers were simple application failure hooks implemented in C, trying to access the stack in whatever context they interrupted. Needless to say, things went dirty quickly.
Implementing all handlers in asm solved the issue of the core locking up on corrupted a SP.

Answer (score 0):

*busFault pending, memFault active* - memFault has caused busError - and it kills the micro

Comment: according to [http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/BGBFCHGC.html] the core will lock up in case a fault occurs when in hardFault/NMI handler, do I get this right? Why do you think this situation escalates to a hardFault, and what can I do to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Exception stacking uses the same stack as the current context. By providing an invalid stack pointer, you've prevented any of the exception handlers being able to complete. Lockup specifically addresses this scenario.

Comment: As far as I know this is why at least the hardFault handler should be able to run even if the stacking was unsuccessful. The handler itself runs on the intact MSP.

Comment: Right. That's why I think in the above scenario the handler should be able to run even though providing false debug information as the stackframe from the thread context is unavailable. But I might be wrong...

Comment: Stacking happens before exception entry. You broke the PSP, so you killed the thread, _and_ you killed the process of reaching the exception handler.